# Twin digits vs edtabular

Tags: reledmac

Everytime I write the same digit twice at the end of line in a edtabular environment, the engine encounters a problem whereby I get the following error:

"There's no line here to end"

It will then proceed to assign a random line as the culprit.

MWE--

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin={2in,0.5in},vmargin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[series={A,B},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\ledlsnotesep=-50pt
\sidenotemargin{inner}
\textwidth = 500pt
\usepackage{setspace}
\AtBeginDocument{\doublespacing}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{SBL BibLit}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=Required]{SBL BibLit}

\begin{document}
\centering
\section*{Fragment V.1 (Fol. 61)}
\beginnumbering
\begin{greek}
\pstart
\begin{edtabularl}
blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&22\\ %PROBLEM HERE
τοῦβαχ&ἀγαθόν σου&τὸ ἀγαθόν σου&τῆς χρηστότητός σου&τῆς ἀγαθωσύνης σου&
\end{edtabularl}
\pend
\end{greek}
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

My solution was to put double digits in a box. So, 22 --> \mbox{22}. That does the trick. But if any of you know a more elegant solution, I welcome it.

Thank you,

Comment: please fix the example so we can debug it, I assume from your tag this is reledmac so I added `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{reledmac}\begin{document}` but got the error `! Paragraph ended before \@ssect was complete.` and fixing that gives `! LaTeX Error: Environment greek undefined.`

Comment: My apologies. I will add include the preamble.

Comment: that seems to be a bug in reledmac, so open an issue on github.

Comment: @Maïeul is this something you do or do I need to do that? I have no idea what it means to "open an issue on github." Thanks!

Comment: it is explained on the handbook. But you can also read https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/